# R plumber not parsing json arguments

Tags: r, json, plumber

According to the [plumber docs](https://www.rplumber.io/index.html), I should be able to pass function arguments in JSON format. Given the following server:

```
#* Return the sum of two numbers
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @post /sum
function(a, b) {
  as.numeric(a) + as.numeric(b)
}
```

If I then start the server:

```
library(plumber)
library(dplyr)
pr("plumber.R") %>%
     pr_run(port=8000)
```

This works as expected:

```
curl --data "a=4&b=3" "http://localhost:8000/sum"
[7]
```

But this does not work, although the docs linked above seem to state it should:

```
curl --data '{"a":4, "b":5}' http://localhost:8000/sum
```

The error I get is:

```
<simpleError in (function (a, b) {    as.numeric(a) + as.numeric(b)})(): argument "a" is missing, with no default>
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Here is my `sessionInfo`:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plumber_1.0.0.9999

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.2      magrittr_2.0.1      R6_2.5.0            later_1.1.0.1      
 [5] promises_1.1.1.9001 tools_4.0.2         swagger_3.33.1      yaml_2.2.1         
 [9] Rcpp_1.0.5          stringi_1.5.3       jsonlite_1.7.2      webutils_1.1       
[13] httpuv_1.5.4        lifecycle_0.2.0     rlang_0.4.9.9000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the plumber documentation has an error. It says:

> You can also send your data as JSON:
>
> ```bash
> $ curl --data '{"a":4, "b":5}' http://localhost:8000/sum`
> ```

But what I think it should read is:

> ```bash
> $ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"a":4, "b":5}' http://localhost:8000/sum`
> ```

In your case, you should also make sure to add `-X POST`, since you use `#* @post /sum`.

Try this on your (not-R) command line:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"a":4, "b":5}' http://localhost:8000/sum
```

---

Explanation:

The reason it errs with `Error: argument "a" is missing, with no default` is because the input parser is normally looking for a pattern of `"a=4&b=3"`. Notably, `name=value`, and among other things, there is no `=` in the json content on which it might be able to find things.

(In my opinion, I think strict enforcement of the input format is good. It would be better if it were to log something saying "unparseable content-type", but that's a different gripe.)

Comment: For me, the single quotes did not work so I had to use: "{\"sex\":2,\"age\":31}". Also another mistake I made, the order of -H and -d is important.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/691

The doc need an update for curl.